# ASP .NET C# MVC 5 Code First Foreign Key Property/Column Names

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm brand-spanking new to MVC and I'm using MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2015 for a ASP .NET C# web application.

Code First.

My goal: define the foreign key relationships in the code, let the scaffolding create the keys in the database.

I'm having great difficulty doing this. I would prefer not to use the [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx) if possible. At the very least, I'd like to understand 1) why I need to use the Fluent API, and 2) actually how to use it.

***Models***

**ApplicationType Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCModelFirstSample.Models
{
    public class ApplicationType
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ApplicationTypeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string ApplicationTypeShortDescription { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string ApplicationTypeLongDescription { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CreatedByUserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ModifiedByUserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, I desire to create some other class that uses an `ApplicationTypeID` as a foreign key. I've created one:

**MVC5Application**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCModelFirstSample.Models
{
    public class MVC5Application
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int MVC5ApplicationID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ApplicationTypeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string MVC5ApplicationDescription { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CreatedByUserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ModifiedByUserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In an of itself, these models work and I can build controllers, and the database gets properly generated, etc. However, there is no linking between the ApplicationTypeID in the MVC5Application table in the database and the ApplicationType table.

Based off some of my research, there was some indication that an auto-generated foreign key relationship might get created, but it wasn't clear. It didn't.

So, my first thought is to add a `[ForeignKey("ApplicationTypeID")]` attribute above the property definition in the `MVCApplication` class.

Doing this, to me, makes sense (whether or not it's actually sensible is another thing all together). Anyway, snippet:

```
namespace MVCModelFirstSample.Models
{
    public class MVC5Application
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int MVC5ApplicationID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationTypeID")]
        public int ApplicationTypeID { get; set; }
```

It builds and when I attempt to add a new MVCApplication via the Create controller action:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: The property 'ApplicationTypeID' cannot be configured as
>   a navigation property. The property  must be a valid entity type and
>   the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter.  For
>   collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T
>   is a valid entity type.

Here is where I get confused. And I swear, I have searched and searched and searched. I'm finding different suggestions, but nothing is clear to me about how to set this up.

One possible option is to declare the class as the key. I guess, maybe, it auto-detects the ID from the class and uses that? Not sure, but hey, worth a try, right? Seems you can pretty-much put anything you want in these string values. No one will complain until it is used.

```
public class MVC5Application
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MVC5ApplicationID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationType")]
    public int ApplicationTypeID { get; set; }
```

Error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ApplicationTypeID'
>   on type 'MVCModelFirstSample.Models.MVC5Application' is  not valid.
>   The navigation property 'ApplicationType' was not found on the
>   dependent type 'MVCModelFirstSample.Models.MVC5Application'.  The Name
>   value should be a valid navigation property name.

That probably wasn't the best idea anyway.

Is it even possible to generate a foreign key relationship via code-first by defining the classes and providing the foreign key? I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible here.

Ideally, I'd like to use keys with database column names that don't necessarily match. For example, I'd have a User table with UserID values that relate to CreatedByUserID in other tables.

With that said, I lead to Fluent API.

I had trouble. Where the heck is my DbContext I need to find and work with? I finally figured it out, I think.

Because I used Internet Authentication, I have IdentityModel.cs which contains the following:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

...which I would then add my override:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

And in the override, I would add my Fluent API.

According to [Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620):

> **Renaming a Foreign Key That Is Not Defined in the Model**
>
> If you choose not to define a foreign key on the CLR type, but want to
>   specify what name it should have in the database, do the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>() 
    .HasRequired(c => c.Department) 
    .WithMany(t => t.Courses) 
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("ChangedDepartmentID"));
```

No. I was not able to use this code, directly. What I had to do was sit back and look at the example classes and relate them to my own classes. I realized I am under some fundamental misapprehension or understanding of how this stuff should work.

I had to modify my classes as such:

```
public class ApplicationType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ApplicationTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ApplicationTypeShortDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string ApplicationTypeLongDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CreatedByUserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ModifiedByUserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MVC5Application> Applications { get; set; }
}

public class MVC5Application
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MVC5ApplicationID { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    //[ForeignKey("ApplicationType")]
    //public int ApplicationTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationType ApplicationType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string MVC5ApplicationDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CreatedByUserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ModifiedByUserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now, following the pattern outlined in the article on Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MVC5Application>()
        .HasRequired(r => r.ApplicationType)
        .WithMany(w => w.Applications)
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("ApplicationTypeID"));

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

And after a great deal of Migration ([Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621)) work:

I got my desired results, I think:

[image]

But, I have to be honest. At this point, this whole process is fairly non-intuitive.

Is there a better way?

Also, if anyone has any additional references on using code-first to create the database tables so that this is a bit more understandable, I'd appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: The Fluent API has more power than the Attribute approach. And you can have your configuration in one place in strongly typed classes.

Comment: If you create a property in MVC5Application of type ApplicationType this will create the relation for you. In the class structure you dont create a property integer for the relationshhip just the instance of the related data.

Comment: Yikes, that's a lot of info. A few basics, EF can build the relationships by convention, annotation or fluent. I like fluent so I can separate my concerns. One glaring error is your use of the ForeignKey attribute - you don't assign that to the foreign key id - you assign it to a navigation property which is the class itself.         [ForeignKey("ApplicationTypeID")]  public ApplicationType ApplicationType { get; set; }

Comment: See this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fluent API you can keep your entities free from persistence dependent stuff and keep your model in a class library without any dependency on EF. I normally create a 2nd project for the DbContext, that contains the configuration and is the only project depending on EF.

If you declare Navigation Properties (like you did in the end with the ApplicationType Property, EF automatically creates the foreign keys for you and it makes it a lot easier to navigate through your object model. Id's are for databases, in your code you want to use properties of real types.

More information about code first you might find in the [EF Core documentation](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the EF Core Documentation is the place to get a solid foundation on this.